# MvxBind:Error: View type not found - BindableListView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I've been using MvvmCross for more than 2 years now but this latest Android issue has be stumped. I am clearly missing something.

I've upgraded my Xamarin and MonoDevelop using the latest release. I've been using Mvx hot tuna 3.5 and tried to upgrade to 3.5.1 with no different result. Basically every single view that uses bindings fail dismally with the MvxBind:Error in the output window the views just turn out blank.

I've also changed by setup class by trying to provide the assemblies manually and also the namespaces. I need to resolve this quite urgently, Stuart please advise.

```
MvxBind:Error:100,93 View type not found - md52d382d08e2b5b5a41f8bed5ba30f5cc4.BindableListView
```

An example of this is a binding in my configuration view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/style_background">
    <Monovage.BindableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Thresholds"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_usagethreshold"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/style_background">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility IsBusy, Converter=Visibility" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Bindable List View is a list view that inherits from the MvxListView

public class BindableListView : MvxListView

Comment: The problem is breaking changes in the latest Xamarin releases - use `[Register(your.namespace.Name)]` with your Android views to make them use readable Java names that correspond to your C# namespaces instead of those stupid MD5 hashes. There's more on this in the Xam release notes - or ask Xam support...

Answer (score 7):

I just dealt with this yesterday using a BindingFlowLayout. I resolved the MvxBind:Error by adjusting the prefix in the layout file...

```
<BindingFlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/AllShowsFlow"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/appmoviesgriditem"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TVShows"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and adding the assemblies setup.

```
protected override IList<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies
    {
        get 
        {
            var assemblies = base.AndroidViewAssemblies;
            assemblies.Add(typeof(MvxExtensions.BindingFlowLayout).Assembly);
            assemblies.Add(typeof(MvxExtensions.FlowLayout).Assembly);
            return assemblies;
        }
    }
```

Based on Stuart's answer here:

[MvxBind:Error: View type not found - mvvmemiextensions.EmiDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389295/mvxbinderror-view-type-not-found-mvvmemiextensions-emidatepicker)

However, this error was benign in my app and it never caused any problems.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but with BindableExpandableListView,
I got the error

```
[MvxBind] 237.25 View type not found - md58cb9ccb4af6afc62c0aa8757d7b275d0.BindableExpandableListView
```

I had this in the layout file

```
<DeapExtensions.Binding.Droid.Views.BindableExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/openExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource WrappedCategories"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/rowopentask"
        local:GroupItemTemplate="@layout/rowcategory" />
```

I just removed all the prefix like so

```
<BindableExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/openExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource WrappedCategories"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/rowopentask"
        local:GroupItemTemplate="@layout/rowcategory" />
```

and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is for MvvmCross to not assume a 1:1 mapping from C# to Java type names, the following code snippet can be used to get the underlying Java type name from the C# type:

```
string javaClassName = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MyActivity));
```